# bash concatenate randomized strings to current list of strings

Tags: bash

I have an array of string `foo bar baz lorem ipsum`

I'm passing this array to another bash script by appending a random password from output of `openssl rand -hex 3`

Expected array output is like
`foo:a6f bar:0o0 baz:5!3 ....`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Loop on your array items, call your openssl for each element, append the array item, `:` and your newly created password to a string, call the script with that new string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one idea.

> Expected array output is like foo:a6f bar:0o0 baz:5!3 ....

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array=(foo bar baz lorem ipsum)

for i in "${array[@]}"; do
  IFS= read -r rand < <(openssl rand -hex 3) &&
  new_array+=("$i":"$rand")
done

printf '%s\n' "${new_array[*]}"
```

---

> I'm passing this array to another bash script by appending a random password from output of openssl rand -hex 3

Using a separate script and feeding the array.

The script named *myscript*

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

new_array=()

for f ; do
  IFS= read -r rand < <(openssl rand -hex 3) &&
  new_array+=("$f":"$rand")
done

printf '%s\n' "${new_array[*]}"
```

---

At the command line.

initialize the array of strings.

```
array=(foo bar baz lorem ipsum)
```

Feed it against *myscript*.

```
myscript "${array[@]}"
```

---

Not sure how you would incorporate the code above in your script though, since we don't know where are the strings is coming from.